# Alien biochemistry

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

My creature  was alien which home was destroyed . It got into another planet similar to earth . Its organs are not like humans. It sustains itself with by passively drawing in body heat and the electricity from the nervous systems of other animals to convert into chemical energy. How does it exactly do this ? What mechanism does it use for its sustenance ?

Comment: What's your creature like? Is it as big as an elephant? As small as a tick? Does it ambush creatures and drain them of their heat and electric impulses until they die or are they parasites that just attach to a host and live off of it? Have you tried thinking of a method but aren't sure if it works?

Answer (score 2):

> It sustains itself with by passively drawing in body heat and the electricity from the nervous systems of other animals to convert into chemical energy. How does it exactly do this ? What mechanism does it use for its sustenance?

**It's a small remora-like parasite.**

Drawing in electricity from a nervous system, or even body heat itself for that matter, is a daunting prospect just given how little energy this is to be obtained from this. In Earth's biosphere, there's no predator which cares about eating its food hot because of just how little energy is gained. To offset this, we need to either (a) murder an large amount of creatures or (b) make the creature really small. (b) is easier from a biological standpoint, so that's the choice. And, just to clarify, when I say 'small', I mean worm-sized at the very largest, probably even smaller than that.

Now it needs to feed off body heat. Certainly it can attempt to kill larger animals and just burrow in their corpses, but that's a terrible idea because a dead animal will cool down and then the process needs to start over again. A much better idea is to non-lethally burrow inside of large animal and just kind of remain there, without affecting the host too much.

Nervous system electricity isn't a good idea, by the way. It can have potentially lethal side effects on the host and the energy output is just terrible. So we're going body heat only.

Out creature is now a small burrowing parasite that dives into host bodies, finds a snug little corner, and just sits there, generating heat. Now, okay, we need to figure out how that works - and the answer is [thermosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosynthesis). This is a *very* primitive form of energy generation (in the sense that the modern human has a superior one), but it's theorized to be the original form of energy generation for all life, so its possible, albeit horribly inefficient. But that's fine, your creature doesn't really expend energy - all it does is invade a host and sleep there.

The life cycle for this creature, now, is slightly complicated, but entirely possible under these constraints, however, that's another question entirely.